# Python - Problema con while y los condicionales

Tags: python, condiciones, while

estoy empezando a aprender programación (python) y me he topado con un problema a la hora de simular el funcionamiento de un cajero.

Lo que espero del programa es que se ejecute el while y espere a que el usuario introduzca la opción seleccionada y a continuación continue comprobando los condicionales, no obstante, no da la opción al usuario de introducir la opción.

```
def borrarPantalla():
    if os.name == 'posix':
       os.system ('clear')
    elif os.name == 'ce' or os.name == 'nt' or os.name == 'dos':
        os.system ('cls')


while True:
    print('.:: Menú principal::;')
    print('==========================================')
    print('\t1. Ingresar saldo en la cuenta')
    print('\t2. Retirar saldo en la cuenta')
    print('\t3. Mostrar saldo disponible\n')
    print('\t4. Salir\n')
    opcion = input('Seleccione una opción: ')

    if (opcion == 1):
        ingreso = float(input('Introduzca la cantidad a ingresar: '))
        dinero += ingreso

        print(f'Su saldo actual es: {dinero}€')

    elif (opcion == 2):
        retiro = float(input('Introduzca la cantidad a retirar: '))
        if (retiro > dinero):
            print('No tiene saldo suficiente')

        else:
            dinero -= retiro

        print(f'Su saldo actual es: {dinero}€')

    elif (opcion == 3):
        print(f'Su saldo actual es: {dinero}€')

    elif (opcion == 4):
        break

    input('Presiona <INTRO> para continuar...')
    borrarPantalla()

print('Gracias por usar nuestros servicios.')
```

*"La mejor forma de solucionar problemas en códigos de programación es buscar a un compañero para que revise tu código. Seguramente él tendrá la mente y las ideas más frescas."*

Comment: Al parecer la sintaxis de esta condición está mal escrita: `else: dinero -= retiro`; debería ser `else: dinero<=retiro`, si eso es lo que quieres decir. Te recomiendo colocar en tu pregunta que tipo de error te arroja.

Comment: Gracias por tu contestación, con dinero -= retiro lo que quiero hacer es restar la cantidad a restar de la variable dinero. En cuanto al error, no lanza ninguno, simplemente se repite el bucle pulses la opción que pulses... es decir, no mira los condicionales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando lees la entrada del teclado con input, estás obteniendo un string, por tanto las comparaciones con números enteros siempre dan `False`

Todo se arregla con una conversión a entero:

```
opcion = int(input('Seleccione una opción: '))
```

Comment: Cierto si, no me di cuenta con convertirlo. Muchas gracias.